# How to say "am getting used to" something

Tags: grammar

Is it まだ慣れてる？

慣れてる means "to be used to something" but if I add まだ does this make clear that I mean "am still getting used to" a new job, a new country, etc, as a process ongoing now. I know that Japanese doesn't have the same sense of present progressive as English so maybe this is not something Japanese people would normally say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common and natural-sounding way to say that would be:

> 「～～に[慣]{な}れて**きて**いる」 using 「くる」 as a subsidiary verb.

Also common would be:

> 「～～に慣れ[始]{はじ}めた**ところ**です」

We do not say 「まだ慣れてる」 to mean anything.  It just makes no sense, sorry to say.

We, however, say 「まだ慣れていない」 in the negative form to mean "to be **not** used to ~~ **yet**".

Comment: Don't understand your notation for 「に慣れ[始]{はじ}めたところです。」 does  [] just mark kanji? So Xに慣れ始めたところです means  "I just started getting used to doing X"

Comment: Also, 慣れてきた means "I got used to" and 慣れてきます means "getting used to" or "will get used to" is it correct?

Comment: @PaulCunningham Aren't you looking at this page with mobile app? We have furigana feature but they don't work on the official app. Try to open it in your browser.